# error[E0658]: destructuring assignments are unstable - Unable to install latest anchor version

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust

When attempting to update to the latest version of anchor (0.25.0) from 0.24.2 I got this error.

```
error[E0658]: destructuring assignments are unstable
   --> /home/name/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/solana-runtime-1.10.29/src/cost_model.rs:100:71
    |
100 |         (tx_cost.builtins_execution_cost, tx_cost.bpf_execution_cost) =
    |         ------------------------------------------------------------- ^
    |         |
    |         cannot assign to this expression
    |
    = note: see issue #71126 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71126> for more information
```

I actually figured out the answer but still wanted to contribute to the solana stack exchange as I searched here and didn't find an answer.

My version of rust was out of date, I updated using "rustup update" and it installed properly afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of rust is out of date, try updating it using `rustup update`

(Adding the answer that was included in the question)